# Como utilizar atributos de uma subclasse de uma classe abstrata?

Tags: android, android-studio, dart

Tenho o seguinte cenário: uma classe abstrata "ListItem" e as classes "HeadingItem" e "Contact".

A relação entre elas é a seguinte:

```
...
}
    abstract class ListItem{

    }

    class HeadingItem implements ListItem{
      String heading;
      HeadingItem(this.heading);
    }

    class Contact implements ListItem{

      Contact(this.id,this.name,this.email,this.phone);

      String id;
      String name;
      String email;
      String phone;

    }
```

Montei o seguinte cenário, onde crio uma `List<ListItem> mixedList` contendo objetos do tipo "Contact" e do tipo "HeadingItem":

```
void funcao(){
...

    List<ListItem> mixedList;
        mixedList.add(Contact("1","nome1","email1","phone1"));
        mixedList.add(Contact("2","nome2","email2","phone2"));
        mixedList.add(Contact("3","nome3","email3","phone3"));
        mixedList.add(HeadingItem("testeHeading"));
...
}
```

De posse dessa `List<ListItem> mixedList` , executo a seguinte iteração:

```
void funcao(){
...
    for(int i = 0 ; i < mixedList.length ; i++){
          if(mixedList[i] is Contact){
            print(mixedList[i].name);
          }
        }
...
}
```

O compilador nem compila, informando "The getter 'name'isn't defined for the class ListItem".

Sob o meu ponto de vista não deveria ocorrer isso, visto que há código do próprio flutter docs que cria cenário parecido.Ver https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list

Dado esse resultado, tentei fazer um casting, onde o compilador deixa de acusar erro em `mixedList[i].name` mas na janela de debug sequer aparece qualquer print:

```
void funcao(){
    ...
        for(int i = 0 ; i < mixedList.length ; i++){
              if(mixedList[i] is Contact){
                print((mixedList[i] as Contact).name);
              }
            }
    ...
    }
```

Diante disso tudo, pergunto como faço para usar o `mixedList[i].name`?

Comment: Isto é muito errado. Mas pelo menos sua pergunta me serviu para alguma coisa. Nunca vou passar perto desse tal de Flutter :)

Answer (score 0):

Atribua o valor de `mixedList[i]` a uma variável antes do `if`, como

```
final item = mixedList[i];
```

O item terá o tipo como `dynamic`, e será definido em tempo de execução.